# How to make visible RegularExpressionValidator?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

I would like to raise error by myself and use reqularexpressionvalidator to show it's text. (My idea is to reuse this control.) I don't remember what property should I use, and what to assign to show the message from control. Can anybody help me please?
How to raise error for this control from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably it is **ErrorMessage**

```
ErrorMessage="Please enter a 4 digit number!"
```

or with more details, use this syntax

```
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtNumber" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="accessID"
    ControlToValidate = "ID of input control to validate"
    ValidationExpression = "the regular expression pattern to test against"
    ErrorMessage = "message to display in ValidationSummary control"
    Text = "message to display in control"
    ForeColor = "color value"
    BackColor = "color value"
    runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Message shows the text next to the control
Error shows the text after validation fails

Some people usually go with `Message="*"` and `Error="Field cannot have special characters"` and ValidationExpression is the regex to compare against, remember to set the ControlToValidate to the Id of your input control.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the validator to a control using it's `ControlToValidate` property.  Set the text using it's `ErrorMessage` property.

Then, if you'd like it to show, you can call `Page.IsValid` on the server, like this:

```
void ValidateBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
       {
          if (Page.IsValid) 
          {
            // do something
          }
       }
```